# Problema con ColorChooser Tkinter Python

Tags: python, tkinter, interfaz-gráfica

buen día, estoy haciendo un programa GUI en tkinter pero tengo un problema... cuando trato de invocar un ColorChooser desde mi programa se abre y todo bien, el problema es que si aprieto el botón de nuevo, se abre otro dialogo de ColorChooser sobre el anterior, entonces lo que quiero es que mi ventana principal del programa pierda el foco para evitar que el usuario habra ColorChoosers infinitamente jaja

```
def elegirColor():
    colorElegido = ColorChooser.askcolor(title='Elige un color')
    tuplaColor = list(colorElegido)
    colorHex = tuplaColor[1] #color en hexadecimal
    print(colorHex)

btnElegirColor = Button(ventanaPrincipal, text='Elige un color', bg='skyblue', command= elegirColor)
btnElegirColor.place(x=20, y=20)
```

[image: Esto es lo que quiero evitar que el usuario haga]

Espero alguien me pueda ayudar, se lo agradecería mucho...

Answer (score 1):

Te comparto mi código como yo lo haría. Espero resuelva tu duda

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import colorchooser

def cambio():
    color = colorchooser.askcolor(title='Elige un color')
    colores = list(color)
    colorHex = colores[1]
    print(colorHex)

raiz = Tk()
boton = Button(raiz, text="Cambio de color", command=cambio)
boton.pack()
raiz.geometry("400x400")
raiz.mainloop()
```

Comment: Muchas gracias bro, ya vi cual fue el error, me salvaste jaja, gracias :D

Comment: @AlejandroGarcía si la respuesta te sirvió, recuerda marcarla como aceptada.